# BeautifulSoup doesnt find some elements while they exists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find an `img` tag with a specific `id`;
This element exists but `BeautifulSoup` doesn't find it!
My code is:

```
    pic=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.imdb.com/media/rm2826217216/nm0334441?ref_=nmmi_mi_all_sf_1")
    pichtml=pic.read()
    picsoup=BeautifulSoup(pichtml)
    picurl=picsoup.find_all("img",{"id":"primary-img"})
```

When I try `picsoup.find_all("img")` only 1 image is found while there are lots of images in page!
What is the problem?

Comment: Your code only returns one image because you used `soup.find` and not `soup.find_all`, as you have commented. Should your code/question be corrected?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using `find_all` and still providing it with an `id`... that should really only return one image...

Comment: @Haidro: for the `picsoup.find` it returns `None`

Comment: @JonClements: with `find_all` it returns empty list! (`ResultSet: []`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced this issue before and I could solve it by specifying a different html parser than the default one. While I don't know the exact reason, I think it's due to [differences in the way each parser treats html](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

So, may be specifying a parser will solve it eg.

```
picsoup=BeautifulSoup(pichtml, 'html.parser')
```